# ASP.NET Error CS1026: ) expected?

Tags: asp.net

why do I see the CS1026 error:) expected at the line below ?

```
<%=Html.BeginForm("AddAdvertisement", "Advertisement"){%> //here
     hello
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this instead ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx)):

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("AddAdvertisement", "Advertisement")) { %> //here
     hello
<% } %>
```

Comment: You're right. What's corious - when I compiled that code @WinXP Pro SP3 everything worked fine - when I compiled it @Win 7 Pro I saw that error.